# Click event queueing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, click, onclicklistener

I am using addEventListener to execute some different code whenever one of a certain number of different buttons is clicked.

I would like to have control over **when** this code is executed. More specifically, I would like click events for all these buttons to be queued so that at any point in the code I can fetch the oldest event that has not yet been fetched, remove it from the queue and execute the corresponding code.

For example, in Rust I was doing this by using the poll() and read() functions from the event module of the crossterm crate ( https://docs.rs/crossterm/latest/crossterm/event/index.html ). The poll() function tells me whether there is an event in the queue and the read() function gives me the oldest event and removes it from the queue.

Is there an easy way to this in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: "*I would like click events for all these buttons to be queued*" that's what happens in the browser anyway. If you click several times, the handlers will be executed in order sequentially. If you really want to handle each click yourself, then you'd have to re-invent the queue and event loop mechanism of JS. But I'm not really sure to what end that would be. Especially considering in order to be notified about the events and respond to them, you'd be relying on the event loop *anyway*.

Comment: It's good to know that events are queued like this by default, thanks! However, what I want is for events to be handled only at specific times, so they should stay in the queue until then.

Comment: Then you need to reinvent the event queue. Do note that you would lose access to parts of it, as the event data parameter would be "dead" after the event fully bubbles. Various parts of it might have wrong information or be unusable. Depending on what you need it for. Or *if*,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a `workQueue = []`, push functions onto it, and then whenever you want to run the "next job", call `workQueue.shift()()`.  E.g. if you want to only run one job a second, you could do:

```js
const workQueue = [];

let i = 0;

document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const job = () => {
        console.log(i++);
    };
    workQueue.push(job);
});

document.querySelector('#run').addEventListener('click', () => {
   runNextJob()
});

const runNextJob = () => workQueue.length && workQueue.shift()()
setInterval(() => {
    runNextJob()
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="add">Add Event</button>

<button id="run">Run Now</button>
```

That being said, you could also just run the job immediately on click and you'd get the same effect, only faster.  But this does give the benefit of being able to "queue up" work, and then whenever you want you can tell it to do the next unit.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I wanted, thanks!